# What is the markup for this table?

Tags: html, markup

[image]

Im really stuck making the markup for this kind of table I almost spend 2hrs reading the difference between rowspan and colspan. Im badly need help for this guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for first two rows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Diversifier Portfolio PDF</td>
        <td>Investment Management</td>
        <td>0.30%</td>
        <td rowspan="2">0.40%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Administration</td>
        <td>0.10%</td>      
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I was too slow :'(

Comment: Thanks guys! the first two rows are working properly. How about the last row? Sorry guys I just badly needed it

Comment: The last row just has a <td rowspan="3"> where you had it before with <td rowspan="2"> because the first and the last column have a height of 3 rows

Comment: Sure :) just ask if you need more help

Comment: Okay thats fine, no problem :)

Comment: @AldrenTerante - Don't forget to accept an answer if you've got a satisfactory answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot  :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Repeat the same for three times

```
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                Divers
            </td>
            <td>
                Invest
            </td>
            <td>
                0.30%
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                0.40%
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Invest
            </td>
            <td>
                0.10%
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```